# can't add yahoo pipes to google reader

Tags: yahoo-pipes, google-reader

for some reason the feed won't load anything when I add it to google reader.

The pipe is very simple, consists of 2 filters only.  Runs fine in yahoo pipes itself, just will not be found in google reader when I attempt to fetch.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Sorry... not really a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

You probably haven't published the pipe to make it publicly available. Since Google Reader needs to access the pipe over the internet, it needs to be public.

Comment: Yes, making the pipe public is important. Also, note that if you're the only one subscribing to this feed in Google Reader it will probably be updated very slowly - only once or twice a day in Reader (popular feeds are updated almost every minute or so).

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me, try using the .rss link
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=fa3405521b5bb6b18e272cb35549e295&_render=rss

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to integrate your feed in Greader is to export the rss feed into an opml file and add it to Google Reader.

It will keep the name of the feeds

Answer (score 0):

First of all: the Pipe does not need to be public to be able to add it to Google Reader. I have dozens of Pipes and I have not published any of them.

On the other hand, I also think there is a problem. When I generate a new Pipe, I cannot immediately add the output to Google Reader. It takes some hours before I am able to add it. I don't know the reason but what I do is the following: I copy the RSS address of the Pipe output to somewhere and try adding that same address a few hours later. The I start seeing the output in Google Reader (and yes, it also detects the name of the Pipe, so you don't have to rename it again).